# How I can add a new column to this data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to generate a new column using this sample data:

```
df<-read.table (text=" id   a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
                       1    5   6   5   6   3   6
                       2    3   4   2   6   2   4",
                header=TRUE)
```

I want to add a new column to get the following data

```
    id  a   m   score
    1   a1  m1  5
    1   a2  m1  6
    1   a3  m1  5
    1   a4  m2  6
    1   a5  m2  3
    1   a6  m2  6
    2   a1  m1  3
    2   a2  m1  4
    2   a3  m1  2
    2   a4  m2  6
    2   a5  m2  2
    2   a6  m2  4
```

The logic is that a1,a2,a3 =m1, a4,a5,a6=m2. I want to generate the column m

I have used these codes:

```
pivot_longer(df, a1:a6, names_to = "a", values_to = "score")
```

I have searched, but I failed to find the solution
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
pivot_longer(df, -id, names_to = "a", values_to = "score") %>%
  mutate(m = case_when(
    a %in% c("a1","a2","a3") ~ "m1",
    a %in% c("a4","a5","a6") ~ "m2",
    TRUE ~ "unk")
  )
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#       id a     score m    
#    <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
#  1     1 a1        5 m1   
#  2     1 a2        6 m1   
#  3     1 a3        5 m1   
#  4     1 a4        6 m2   
#  5     1 a5        3 m2   
#  6     1 a6        6 m2   
#  7     2 a1        3 m1   
#  8     2 a2        4 m1   
#  9     2 a3        2 m1   
# 10     2 a4        6 m2   
# 11     2 a5        2 m2   
# 12     2 a6        4 m2
```

Depending on how you want to maintain your mapping from `m` to `a`, here's an alternative to `case_when`:

```r
groups <- tribble(
  ~m,  ~a,
  "m1", "a1",
  "m1", "a2",
  "m1", "a3",
  "m2", "a4",
  "m2", "a5",
  "m2", "a6"
)

pivot_longer(df, -id, names_to = "a", values_to = "score") %>%
  left_join(groups, by = "a")
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#       id a     score m    
#    <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
#  1     1 a1        5 m1   
#  2     1 a2        6 m1   
#  3     1 a3        5 m1   
#  4     1 a4        6 m2   
#  5     1 a5        3 m2   
#  6     1 a6        6 m2   
#  7     2 a1        3 m1   
#  8     2 a2        4 m1   
#  9     2 a3        2 m1   
# 10     2 a4        6 m2   
# 11     2 a5        2 m2   
# 12     2 a6        4 m2
```

I find it usually very straight-forward to maintain the `groups` frame on its own: it can be in its own CSV, and therefore edited/maintained via whatever you prefer (including excel/libreoffice/calc).

Answer (score 0):

**[This answers using a retired function - I leave the answers as a reminder that `gather` & `spread` is outdated - please consider answers using `pivot` instead]**

I am using `dplyr` & `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(a, score, a1:a6) %>%
  mutate(m = case_when(
    a %in% c("a1", "a2", "a3") ~ "m1",
    a %in% c("a4", "a5", "a6") ~ "m2"),
    TRUE ~ "Unknown") %>%
  select(id, a, m, score)
```

Ouput

```
   id  a  m score
1   1 a1 m1     5
2   2 a1 m1     3
3   1 a2 m1     6
4   2 a2 m1     4
5   1 a3 m1     5
6   2 a3 m1     2
7   1 a4 m2     6
8   2 a4 m2     6
9   1 a5 m2     3
10  2 a5 m2     2
11  1 a6 m2     6
12  2 a6 m2     4
```

Comment: `tidyr::gather` is in a ["retired" state](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/R/gather.R#L4). It is still working just fine, though it will (at some point soon) migrate to a "deprecated" status and eventually removed. As the docs say, it is being replaced by `pivot_longer`, which supports much more functionality than `gather`. I suggest that if you're learning this "pivot" action now, then it is better to learn the more-powerful `pivot_longer` function instead of `gather`.